# Find if a value exists in a Google sheet on a certain column, in all the rows above the current row based on 2 criterias

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have the following scenario:

- columns from A-Z and 100 rows
- in each row for the Z column I want to find if the value in A column from the current row exists in the rows above in A column
- then if exists, I would like to find if the B column for the matching rows have the cell completed with a value
- for all the rows that are matching I would to receive the matching rows in an array list, not as rows or at least to be able to put a value like "mathing"/"not matching"
- this should be an array formula

I've tried something like this, only for the first criteria, but somehow it checks only the current row.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(ROW(Z2:Z)>2, IF(MATCH(A2:A,$A$2:A&ROW(A2:A)-1),"matching","not matching"),"not matching"))
```

- I check to see if it's the first row (as it has headers), and if it's the first row, then surely it can't have any data matching above

It will be great to have it as a google sheet formula but if it's not possible it could also be a google app script

Comment: I'd advice to add a screenshot of your sheet (columns A, B and Z): what the desired outcome should look like

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  osh.clearContents();
  const dsr = 2;
  const vs = sh.getRange(dsr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - dsr + 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getDisplayValues();
  let o = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (i > 0) {
      let as = vs.map(r => r[0]).slice(0, i);// suggested by DoubleUnary
      let bs = vs.map(r => r[1]).slice(0, i);//suggested by DoubleUnary
      let idx = as.indexOf(r[25]);
      if (~idx && bs[idx]) {
        o.push(['yes', dsr + i, dsr + idx, r[25], bs[idx]])
      } else {
        o.push(['no', dsr + i, ~idx ? as[idx] : '', r[25], ~idx ? bs[idx] : '']);
      }
    }
  });
  o.unshift(['Value', 'Test Row', 'Result Row', 'Z value', 'B value'])
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o));
  osh.getRange(1, 1, o.length, o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

My Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 | COL5 | COL6 | COL7 | COL8 | COL9 | COL10 | COL11 | COL12 | COL13 | COL14 | COL15 | COL16 | COL17 | COL18 | COL19 | COL20 | COL21 | COL22 | COL23 | COL24 | COL25 | COL26 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | 8 | 18 | 3 | 15 | 15 | 6 | 6 | 18 | 2 | 10 | 19 | 14 | 5 | 16 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 13 | 15 | 14 | 10 | 13 | 19 | 7 |
| 14 | 5 | 18 | 12 | 12 | 3 | 5 | 5 | 12 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 19 | 17 | 13 | 14 | 2 | 6 | 2 | 0 | 18 | 15 | 16 | 1 | 1 | 15 |
| 14 | 8 | 18 | 19 | 18 | 19 | 14 | 11 | 9 | 2 | 12 | 4 | 19 | 8 | 7 | 17 | 2 | 5 | 17 | 12 | 3 | 18 | 6 | 15 | 12 | 17 |
| 12 | 15 | 1 | 11 | 2 | 14 | 4 | 12 | 15 | 4 | 2 | 7 | 13 | 12 | 4 | 10 | 0 | 2 | 9 | 2 | 15 | 12 | 18 | 7 | 10 | 6 |
| 15 | 8 | 3 | 11 | 3 | 11 | 8 | 2 | 0 | 12 | 18 | 12 | 17 | 3 | 3 | 10 | 5 | 18 | 0 | 6 | 19 | 12 | 11 | 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 16 | 16 | 7 | 14 | 12 | 3 | 1 | 9 | 0 | 1 | 9 | 4 | 17 | 11 | 18 | 2 | 4 | 16 | 13 | 4 | 1 | 3 | 4 | 13 | 9 | 8 |
| 11 | 18 | 9 | 9 | 10 | 17 | 6 | 16 | 8 | 10 | 15 | 10 | 18 | 1 | 2 | 9 | 10 | 18 | 13 | 0 | 11 | 4 | 7 | 2 | 0 | 18 |
| 3 | 5 | 1 | 5 | 18 | 17 | 4 | 8 | 2 | 4 | 10 | 13 | 7 | 10 | 9 | 6 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 7 | 12 | 12 | 6 | 0 | 3 | 7 |
| 3 | 3 | 19 | 4 | 2 | 5 | 0 | 9 | 5 | 14 | 0 | 2 | 15 | 9 | 18 | 6 | 1 | 15 | 5 | 5 | 1 | 12 | 4 | 7 | 9 | 3 |
| 19 | 19 | 15 | 16 | 12 | 18 | 13 | 0 | 12 | 4 | 12 | 4 | 1 | 8 | 19 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 8 | 14 | 6 | 10 | 0 | 16 | 14 | 14 |
| 10 | 8 | 3 | 15 | 5 | 13 | 9 | 13 | 10 | 6 | 16 | 2 | 15 | 3 | 2 | 16 | 19 | 2 | 14 | 1 | 10 | 1 | 1 | 5 | 5 | 10 |
| 8 |  | 3 | 8 | 17 | 13 | 15 | 8 | 9 | 6 | 4 | 2 | 14 | 6 | 4 | 1 | 6 | 14 | 8 | 9 | 11 | 12 | 3 | 18 | 5 | 14 |
| 9 | 18 | 2 | 12 | 17 | 2 | 17 | 10 | 0 | 11 | 7 | 11 | 2 | 0 | 11 | 15 | 6 | 7 | 13 | 10 | 18 | 17 | 6 | 19 | 12 | 14 |
| 15 | 7 | 12 | 5 | 0 | 17 | 15 | 2 | 2 | 18 | 6 | 7 | 13 | 1 | 10 | 19 | 9 | 7 | 13 | 15 | 13 | 7 | 18 | 11 | 13 | 10 |
| 8 | 1 | 10 | 5 | 17 | 9 | 9 | 5 | 14 | 3 | 3 | 1 | 19 | 7 | 13 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 2 | 12 | 17 | 3 | 12 | 9 | 0 | 10 |
| 9 | 15 | 6 | 14 | 18 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 4 | 9 | 19 | 4 | 9 | 15 | 11 | 0 | 3 | 10 | 19 | 5 | 18 | 16 | 10 | 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 1 | 1 | 6 | 8 | 10 | 9 | 8 | 19 | 4 | 11 | 18 | 12 | 14 | 8 | 4 | 5 | 11 | 8 | 17 | 5 | 7 | 13 | 13 | 16 | 14 | 8 |
| 7 | 14 | 7 | 18 | 9 | 3 | 11 | 0 | 1 | 7 | 19 | 8 | 6 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 2 | 4 | 11 | 3 | 7 | 5 | 5 | 9 | 16 | 15 |
| 7 | 6 | 4 | 6 | 7 | 17 | 8 | 13 | 10 | 2 | 9 | 18 | 0 | 13 | 12 | 4 | 13 | 9 | 4 | 19 | 4 | 7 | 10 | 17 | 1 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 | 7 | 12 | 3 | 19 | 19 | 7 | 1 | 11 | 9 | 9 | 9 | 7 | 5 | 6 | 8 | 7 | 0 | 11 | 19 | 6 | 17 | 12 | 1 | 18 |

Results:

| Value | Test Row | Result Row | Z value | B value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| no | 3 |  | 15 |  |
| no | 4 |  | 17 |  |
| no | 5 |  | 6 |  |
| no | 6 |  | 5 |  |
| no | 7 |  | 8 |  |
| no | 8 |  | 18 |  |
| no | 9 |  | 7 |  |
| yes | 10 | 9 | 3 | 5 |
| yes | 11 | 3 | 14 | 5 |
| no | 12 |  | 10 |  |
| yes | 13 | 3 | 14 | 5 |
| yes | 14 | 3 | 14 | 5 |
| yes | 15 | 12 | 10 | 8 |
| yes | 16 | 12 | 10 | 8 |
| yes | 17 | 2 | 4 | 4 |
| no | 18 | 8 | 8 |  |
| yes | 19 | 6 | 15 | 8 |
| no | 20 |  | 5 |  |
| no | 21 |  | 18 |  |

Comment: This calls `getRange().getDisplayValues()` repeatedly. Consider something like
`const as = vs.map(row => row[0]).slice(0, i + 1);`
instead. Cryptic variable names like `osh`, `vsh`, `vs` `o` and `as` hurt readability.

Comment: Understood, but your code will be _read_ many times by others. See [Clean Code JavaScript](https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript). To get the columns A and above the current row, use the `map().slice()` pattern I mentioned. Alternatively, simply check whether `indexOf() < i`.

Comment: @doubleunary It's not exactly cryptic though.`o` =output  `osh`=output sheet, `vs` = values, `as`= column A values

Comment: Yes. Those longer variable names would be much more readable than the one- to three-letter names.

Comment: Hmm... I think both me and Cooper may have a one-off error in the `slice()`. If _all_ the rows above the current row should be included, and the current row should _not_ be included, consider `slice(0, i)` — OK, Cooper fixed it, all fine.